# UITextField Editing Changed not call

Tags: ios, swift

I got a `UITextField` *zipTextField* and use `UIPicker` to change the text. And I want to know when the *zipTextField* is changed.

I put this program in my `ViewController`

```
@IBAction func textFieldEditingDidChange(sender: AnyObject){
    print("textField:\(zipTextField.text)")
}
```

And Connected to the View with **Editing Changed** Event
[image: connect to the view]

But the function didn't call when *zipTextField* has changed

Otherwise when I connect `textFieldEditingDidChange` to **Editing Did End** or **Editing Did Begin**  *textFieldEditingDidChange* will be called

Comment: are you tried with programmatically add target for same?

Comment: use TextField inputAccessoryView  as pickerview

Comment: @NiravHathi Yes when I add target programmatically had same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `EditingChanged` on action. It works on mine.

Answer (score 24):

If you have implemented the delegate method

```
textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String)
```

and returned `false`, the event is not fired.

Usually this is because you're trying to manually set textfield's value (`textField.text = newValue`) preventing the user input.

If so, you have to add:

```
textField.sendActions(for: .editingChanged)
```

before returning `false` and after `textField.text = newValue` in the delegate method. This will send the `UIControl` `Event` back to your observer.

Answer (score 4):

If you change your text field text by code like this:

```
myTextField.text = ""
```

you can raise or call (or fire) delegates and targets like this:

```
    myTextField.text = ""
    myTextField.sendActions(for: .editingChanged)
```

Answer (score 3):

If delegate function

```
textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String)
```

returns `false`,
then function that set on `.editingChanged` will not call.

Answer (score 1):

You say you use an instance of a `UIPicker` to change the text which would lead me to believe you are programmatically changing the `UITextField` based on `UIPicker` valueChanged callbacks. Programmatically changing `UITextField.text` does not call the delegate method.